# supress cat output in following cmd in shell script

Tags: linux

curl=`-c cat <<EOS
curl -s https://api.openai.com/v1/completions 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H "Authorization: Bearer foo" 
-d '{
"model": "text-davinci-003",
"prompt": "$1",
"max_tokens": 4000,
"temperature": $2

}' 
--insecure | jq '.choices[]'
EOS`

eval  ${curl} | tee  $newFileName

Comment: Please format the code nicely. It is enough to put it between two lines containing only `\`\`\``. It is even better if the line before the code reads `\`\`\`shell`.

Comment: Why so complicate?

Comment: `-c` should not stay there. The first word of the command line is the command name (unless it is an assignment but this isn't one). It produces the error `-c: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and `eval`. They only make the things more complicated than they need to be.

I suspect that you used command substitution to get the expanded the values of `$1` and `$2` in the JSON but this is not the right way to do it. If `$1` contains `"` the generated JSON becomes invalid. The same if `$2` is not a number.

The code is even vulnerable to data injection. If `$1` contains the value `blah", "model": "foo` and the value of `$2` is `0`, the argument passed to `-d` becomes:

```js
{ "model": "text-davinci-003", "prompt": "blah", "model": "foo", "max_tokens": 4000, "temperature": 0 }
```

It is not valid JSON (it contains the key `model` twice) but most JSON parsers accept it and they usually use the last value assigned to the key (probably because they do not check for key uniqueness).

This makes the API handle this input object:

```js
{ prompt": "blah", "model": "foo", "max_tokens": 4000, "temperature": 0 }
```

It is not easy to remove the vulnerability using what the shell script offers. You can attempt to replace `"` with `\"` but this leads to more problems (and there must be escaped many characters, anyway).

The easiest solution for this is to use [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/) or other JSON manipulating tool.

Using `jq`, the code would be like this:

```bash
# Generate the data object using `jq`...
# ...and store it into a separate variable for readability
DATA=$(jq -n -c --arg prompt "$1" --arg temp "$2" '{ 
  model: "text-davinci-003",
  prompt: $prompt,
  max_tokens: 4000,
  temperature: $temp
}')

curl -s \
  https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer foo" \
  -d "$DATA" \
  --insecure | 
jq '.choices[]' |
tee "$newFileName"
```